# django-avatar strange error

Tags: python, django

I'm using django-avatar and my template have:

```
{% load i18n avatar_tags %}
{% render_avatar avatar 100 %}
```

and I get this error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://test.me/profile/myuser

Django Version: 1.3
Python Version: 2.6.6
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'test',
 'avatar']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Template error:
In template /srv/www/test.me/localhost/test/templates/profile.html, error at line 23
   Caught VariableDoesNotExist while rendering: Failed lookup for key [avatar] in u'[{}, {\'csrf_token\': <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0xb93445ac>}, {\'perms\': <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0xb9344cec>, \'messages\': <django.contrib.messages.storage.user_messages.LegacyFallbackStorage object at 0xb936258c>, \'user\': <django.utils.functional.SimpleLazyObject object at 0xb9344bcc>}, {}, {\'LANGUAGES\': ((\'ar\', \'Arabic\'), (\'az\', \'Azerbaijani\'), (\'bg\', \'Bulgarian\'), (\'bn\', \'Bengali\'), (\'bs\', \'Bosnian\'), (\'ca\', \'Catalan\'), (\'cs\', \'Czech\'), (\'cy\', \'Welsh\'), (\'da\', \'Danish\'), (\'de\', \'German\'), (\'el\', \'Greek\'), (\'en\', \'English\'), (\'en-gb\', \'British English\'), (\'es\', \'Spanish\'), (\'es-ar\', \'Argentinian Spanish\'), (\'es-mx\', \'Mexican Spanish\'), (\'es-ni\', \'Nicaraguan Spanish\'), (\'et\', \'Estonian\'), (\'eu\', \'Basque\'), (\'fa\', \'Persian\'), (\'fi\', \'Finnish\'), (\'fr\', \'French\'), (\'fy-nl\', \'Frisian\'), (\'ga\', \'Irish\'), (\'gl\', \'Galician\'), (\'he\', \'Hebrew\'), (\'hi\', \'Hindi\'), (\'hr\', \'Croatian\'), (\'hu\', \'Hungarian\'), (\'id\', \'Indonesian\'), (\'is\', \'Icelandic\'), (\'it\', \'Italian\'), (\'ja\', \'Japanese\'), (\'ka\', \'Georgian\'), (\'km\', \'Khmer\'), (\'kn\', \'Kannada\'), (\'ko\', \'Korean\'), (\'lt\', \'Lithuanian\'), (\'lv\', \'Latvian\'), (\'mk\', \'Macedonian\'), (\'ml\', \'Malayalam\'), (\'mn\', \'Mongolian\'), (\'nl\', \'Dutch\'), (\'no\', \'Norwegian\'), (\'nb\', \'Norwegian Bokmal\'), (\'nn\', \'Norwegian Nynorsk\'), (\'pa\', \'Punjabi\'), (\'pl\', \'Polish\'), (\'pt\', \'Portuguese\'), (\'pt-br\', \'Brazilian Portuguese\'), (\'ro\', \'Romanian\'), (\'ru\', \'Russian\'), (\'sk\', \'Slovak\'), (\'sl\', \'Slovenian\'), (\'sq\', \'Albanian\'), (\'sr\', \'Serbian\'), (\'sr-latn\', \'Serbian Latin\'), (\'sv\', \'Swedish\'), (\'ta\', \'Tamil\'), (\'te\', \'Telugu\'), (\'th\', \'Thai\'), (\'tr\', \'Turkish\'), (\'uk\', \'Ukrainian\'), (\'ur\', \'Urdu\'), (\'vi\', \'Vietnamese\'), (\'zh-cn\', \'Simplified Chinese\'), (\'zh-tw\', \'Traditional Chinese\')), \'LANGUAGE_BIDI\': False, \'LANGUAGE_CODE\': \'en-us\'}, {\'MEDIA_URL\': \'http://test.me/media/\'}, {\'STATIC_URL\': \'/static/\'}, {\'messages\': <django.contrib.messages.storage.user_messages.LegacyFallbackStorage object at 0xb936258c>}, {\'messages\': [], \'user\': <User: myuser>, \'form\': <localhost.test.forms.messagesForm object at 0xb936270c>, \'unread_messages\': []}, {\'block\': <Block Node: content. Contents: [<Text Node: \'\n<center>\n    \'>, <If node>, <Text Node: \'\n    \n<h2>Describe \'>, <Variable Node: user.username>, <Text Node: \' in three messages!</h2>\n\n<d\'>, <django.template.base.SimpleNode object at 0xb937772c>, <Text Node: \'\n</div>\n\n<form id="messages_\'>, <Variable Node: user.id>, <Text Node: \'" id="id_user" /></li> \n \'>, <If node>, <Text Node: \'\n<input type="submit" val\'>, <If node>, <Text Node: \'\n\n\'>]>}]'
   13 :     <ul class="messages" style="display: none">


   14 :         {% for message in messages %}


   15 :         <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>


   16 :         {% endfor %}


   17 :     </ul>


   18 :     {% endif %}


   19 :     


   20 : <h2>Describe {{ user.username }} in three messages!</h2>


   21 : 


   22 : <div id="avatar_box">


   23 :      {% render_avatar avatar 100 %} 


   24 : </div>


   25 : 


   26 : <form id="messages_form" action="" method="post">


   27 :     <ul> 


   28 :     <li><input type="text" name="message_1" id="id_message_1" /></li> 


   29 :     <li><input type="text" name="message_2" id="id_message_2" /></li> 


   30 :     <li><input type="text" name="message_3" id="id_message_3" />


   31 :         <input type="hidden" name="user" value="{{user.id}}" id="id_user" /></li> 


   32 :         </ul>


   33 :         {% if form.errors %}


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/srv/www/test.me/localhost/test/views.py" in profile
  102.              'unread_messages': unread_messages})
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render
  44.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs),
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  188.         return t.render(context_instance)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/template/base.py" in render
  123.             return self._render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/template/base.py" in _render
  117.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/template/base.py" in render
  744.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  73.             result = node.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  127.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/template/base.py" in _render
  117.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/template/base.py" in render
  744.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  73.             result = node.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  64.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/template/base.py" in render
  744.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  73.             result = node.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/template/base.py" in render
  880.                     resolved_vars = [var.resolve(context) for var in self.vars_to_resolve]
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  653.             value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/template/base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  692.                             raise VariableDoesNotExist("Failed lookup for key [%s] in %r", (bit, current)) # missing attribute

Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError at /profile/myuser
Exception Value: Caught VariableDoesNotExist while rendering: Failed lookup for key [avatar] in u'[{}, {\'csrf_token\': <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0xb93445ac>}, {\'perms\': <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0xb9344cec>, \'messages\': <django.contrib.messages.storage.user_messages.LegacyFallbackStorage object at 0xb936258c>, \'user\': <django.utils.functional.SimpleLazyObject object at 0xb9344bcc>}, {}, {\'LANGUAGES\': ((\'ar\', \'Arabic\'), (\'az\', \'Azerbaijani\'), (\'bg\', \'Bulgarian\'), (\'bn\', \'Bengali\'), (\'bs\', \'Bosnian\'), (\'ca\', \'Catalan\'), (\'cs\', \'Czech\'), (\'cy\', \'Welsh\'), (\'da\', \'Danish\'), (\'de\', \'German\'), (\'el\', \'Greek\'), (\'en\', \'English\'), (\'en-gb\', \'British English\'), (\'es\', \'Spanish\'), (\'es-ar\', \'Argentinian Spanish\'), (\'es-mx\', \'Mexican Spanish\'), (\'es-ni\', \'Nicaraguan Spanish\'), (\'et\', \'Estonian\'), (\'eu\', \'Basque\'), (\'fa\', \'Persian\'), (\'fi\', \'Finnish\'), (\'fr\', \'French\'), (\'fy-nl\', \'Frisian\'), (\'ga\', \'Irish\'), (\'gl\', \'Galician\'), (\'he\', \'Hebrew\'), (\'hi\', \'Hindi\'), (\'hr\', \'Croatian\'), (\'hu\', \'Hungarian\'), (\'id\', \'Indonesian\'), (\'is\', \'Icelandic\'), (\'it\', \'Italian\'), (\'ja\', \'Japanese\'), (\'ka\', \'Georgian\'), (\'km\', \'Khmer\'), (\'kn\', \'Kannada\'), (\'ko\', \'Korean\'), (\'lt\', \'Lithuanian\'), (\'lv\', \'Latvian\'), (\'mk\', \'Macedonian\'), (\'ml\', \'Malayalam\'), (\'mn\', \'Mongolian\'), (\'nl\', \'Dutch\'), (\'no\', \'Norwegian\'), (\'nb\', \'Norwegian Bokmal\'), (\'nn\', \'Norwegian Nynorsk\'), (\'pa\', \'Punjabi\'), (\'pl\', \'Polish\'), (\'pt\', \'Portuguese\'), (\'pt-br\', \'Brazilian Portuguese\'), (\'ro\', \'Romanian\'), (\'ru\', \'Russian\'), (\'sk\', \'Slovak\'), (\'sl\', \'Slovenian\'), (\'sq\', \'Albanian\'), (\'sr\', \'Serbian\'), (\'sr-latn\', \'Serbian Latin\'), (\'sv\', \'Swedish\'), (\'ta\', \'Tamil\'), (\'te\', \'Telugu\'), (\'th\', \'Thai\'), (\'tr\', \'Turkish\'), (\'uk\', \'Ukrainian\'), (\'ur\', \'Urdu\'), (\'vi\', \'Vietnamese\'), (\'zh-cn\', \'Simplified Chinese\'), (\'zh-tw\', \'Traditional Chinese\')), \'LANGUAGE_BIDI\': False, \'LANGUAGE_CODE\': \'en-us\'}, {\'MEDIA_URL\': \'http://test.me/media/\'}, {\'STATIC_URL\': \'/static/\'}, {\'messages\': <django.contrib.messages.storage.user_messages.LegacyFallbackStorage object at 0xb936258c>}, {\'messages\': [], \'user\': <User: myuser>, \'form\': <localhost.test.forms.messagesForm object at 0xb936270c>, \'unread_messages\': []}, {\'block\': <Block Node: content. Contents: [<Text Node: \'\n<center>\n    \'>, <If node>, <Text Node: \'\n    \n<h2>Describe \'>, <Variable Node: user.username>, <Text Node: \' in three messages!</h2>\n\n<d\'>, <django.template.base.SimpleNode object at 0xb937772c>, <Text Node: \'\n</div>\n\n<form id="messages_\'>, <Variable Node: user.id>, <Text Node: \'" id="id_user" /></li> \n \'>, <If node>, <Text Node: \'\n<input type="submit" val\'>, <If node>, <Text Node: \'\n\n\'>]>}]'
```

It's so strange, because in another template it works without errors.

Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: Are you passing in the variable 'avatar' from the view to the template?

Comment: @Alex Jillard What should be variable 'avatar'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [django-avatar docs](https://github.com/ericflo/django-avatar/blob/master/docs/usage.txt):

`{% render_avatar avatar [size in pixels] %}`

Given an actual `avatar.models.Avatar` object instance, renders an HTML `img` tag to represent that avatar at the requested size.

So, in your view, you need to get the avatar associated with the user:
`avatar = Avatar.objects.get(user=request.user`)

Then pass that variable into the template.

Comment: how can I import avatar model? avatar.models.Avatar doesn't work.

Comment: I've copied all avatar directory to my project and now I can import avatar. The problem is .get doesn't work because `MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one Avatar -- it returned 3` How can I fix?

Comment: You can use .filter() instead of .get(), although you'll need to figure out which of the returned avatars should be used.

Comment: Fixed with: avatar = `Avatar.objects.filter(user=target_user).order_by('-primary')[0]`